# Foreign key relationship in LINQ for Windows Phone Mango app

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-objects, windows-phone-7

I'm just getting started writing an app for WP (Mango), and am running into issues related to how to map a foreign key relationship for a lookup table using LINQ. The MSDN docs didnt seem to help (maybe i'm looking in the wrong place). Basically, I have 2 tables,

OrderType  (this consists of lookup data referenced by Orders)

Orders  (this will have a column called OrderTypeID pointing back to the above table)

basically a 1-to-many relationship.

Here's how I've described in LINQ:

```
[Table(Name = "OrderTypes")]
public partial class OrderType
{
    private Int16 _OrderTypeID;
    private string _Name;
    private string _ShortName;

    [Column(Storage = "_OrderTypeID", DbType = "Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull=false)]
    public Int16 Id {get; set;}

    [Column(Storage = "_Name", DbType = "NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [Column(Storage= "_ShortName", DbType= "NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string ShortName {get;set;}
}

[Table(Name = "Orders")]
public partial class Order
{
    private Int16 _OrderID;
    private Int16 _OrderTypeID;
    private string _Description;

    [Column(Storage = "_OrderID", DbType = "Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Int16 Id {get;set;}

    [Column(DbType = "Int", CanBeNull= true)]
    public Int16 OrderTypeID { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(1000) NULL", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

I confused re: how to use the [EntityRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348960.aspx) and/or [EntitySet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341748.aspx) classes to describe this relationship in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `EntitySet` is on the "1" side, it contains the entities on the "many" side.
- `EntityRef` is on an entity of the "many" side, referring to the (parent) entity on the "1" side.

In your case Order would have an `EntityRef<OrderType>`. OrderType, in turn, could have an 
`EntitySet<Order>`, although I'd think the latter would not make much sense (semantically one would probably not say that an OrderType "has" orders, like an Order "has" order lines).

In the Adventureworks database, when mapping a similar relationship, Product and ProductCategory, the Product class has a `ProductCategory` property:

```
private EntityRef<ProductCategory> _ProductCategory;

[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Storage="_ProductCategory",
    ThisKey="ProductCategoryID", OtherKey="ProductCategoryID", IsForeignKey=true)]
public ProductCategory ProductCategory
{
  get { return this._ProductCategory.Entity; }
  set { this._ProductCategory.Entity = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I had a follow up question; but being new to StackOverflow, I wasnt sure if i should post a brand new post to ask that, or whether it's acceptable to ask it here. I'll ask here anyway (I can always make it into a new post, if needed)


Could you give me an example of how i would insert / update a row into Orders using a valid OrderType ?
Do I have to do a separate query first to get the OrderTypeID and then use that into my insert / update stmt for Order ?

Comment: You'd have to query OrderType to get the id and either set the Id in Order, or an OrderType property (EntityRef). If you need more help it's indeed better to ask a new question (SO likes to have one topic per thread). But this is fairly trivial, so I think you can find other posts on similar problems.